# Fourier transform and Laplace transform to solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Generally we know that both Fourier transform and Laplace transform are used to solve differential equation, first of all let us recall both forms, first Fourier transform:

[image]

Sometimes instead of $-2*\pi*f$, it is written $\omega$, and we know also Laplace transform:

[image]

In some cases the lower bound starts at $-\infty$, and we know that:

$s=\sigma+\omega*t$, which means that Fourier transform is a special case of Laplace when $\sigma=0$.

But both methods is used to solve differential equations, my question us following  how could I guess which method should I used in given concrete example? Laplace transform is used to transform a differential equation into an algebraic equation which simplifies things, but what about the Fourier transform? What is its goal in solving differential equations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The goals of both transform techniques is to convert an ordinary differential equation into an algebraic one (and a partial differential equation into an ordinary differential equation).  The difference is that the domain of the differential operators for which a Fourier tranform applies is $(-\infty,\infty)$, while that for which Laplace applies is $[0,\infty)$.  Thus, LT's are used in initial value problems, while FT's are used when the function is applied over the whole real line.

Comment: thanks for reply,just one question if there is given initial value and i use fourier transform,will my attempt fail to solve such problem?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: it just may not make any sense.  If you have an initial condition, then you have a "boundary" at $t=0$.  Typically, the domain of such problems is $t \ge 0$, so FT would be unwieldy.